# How to get the bandwidth usages in my WIFI including from mobile devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android, bandwidth, wifi-configuration

I have set up a wireless network(Binatone router) for my home.I have 3 laptop usages and two mobile usages,out which which one is iphone and other is android.I want to know how much bandwidth each and every devices have used including phones as well.
I have tried several bandwidth usage tools like colasoft capsa but this tool not showing the android phone usages.
So can anyone suggest me some (Incredible:) ) tools so that i can monitor all my network through it (including android phones usage).

Comment: What wifi Router do you have ?

Comment: I have Binatone router.

Comment: @Sathya .If this question is duplicate can u provide me the link of original question.

Comment: @forgotten_legend http://i.stack.imgur.com/F5WfW.png

Answer (score -1):

Your Router may have options to show bandwidth.
In order to log into with your browser you'll need your routers IP address.
The easiest way to obtain this is to:

- click Winkey and "R", type in `cmd.exe`, click run
- type `ipconfig`.

The command will print its output in the screen.
You are looking for "default gateway" (it should be something like `192.168.1.1`). 
Type this number into your browser.  (e.g. `http://192.168.1.1`).
You will most likely need a *username* and *password* for the router, which depends on the model that you have (you can find a default combo [Here](http://www.routerpasswords.com/).
You may need to look around for bandwidth info, or your router may not have it.

Comment: Welcome on superuser. Remember that when you know a solution of a problem you need few lines to summarize it, but the one that read for the first time will find more difficulties...

Comment: Thanks for the reply,But my router config panel does not have these facilities.Though anyone can suggest me some tools which will be great.

Comment: What ISP do you use (Comcast/AT&T/TimeWarnerCable?etc)?

Comment: I am using Airtel....

Comment: While i am not to familiar with airtel, according to [this](http://www.labnol.org/india/check-airtel-internet-usage/21033/) link you can view usage on your account after signing in